# CSS/Javascript (or JQuery) tutorials on combo box and Facebook-like Message composer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

1) I want to redesign a combo box using CSS and (minimal or none if necessary) javascript. I was wondering if there are good tutorials out there you've come across that can help me with it.

2) For Facebook users, you are aware that you can type 1 or more recipients on the address bar and it'll create a "button" around the user. How does Facebook do it? Is there any tutorials out there?

3) How to do autocomplete dropdown box in Javascript?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You will need to use some javascript. I'd suggested getting familiar with jquery.
   http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/03/11-jquery-plugins-to-enhance-html-dropdowns/ should give you what you need to get started.

2) I've copied this feature myself...and its not easy. I don't know of any tutorials out there. But I'll tell you that it utilizes autocomplete.

3) http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete should do it for you. Once again: use jQuery.

Comment: Thanks, and I use jQuery so that's not an issue.

and how did you do number 2?

Comment: Oh yeah, I need to design a dropdown Combo box from scratch...sorry I never mentioned that.

Comment: @TheEliteGentleman, may I ask you to have a visit at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554666/type-show-a-name-list-like-facebook-status-box/9554760#comment12110040_9554760 ? I don't know whether such a request is valid in SOF.