# type @, show a name list like facebook status box

Tags: javascript, jquery

in facebook status box, if you type '@', then a list of friends' names appear. I am trying to implement such a status box.

But the problems are:

On typing '@', where should the 'div's location be and how  to show the list? I just can't make anything out of it.

I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497824/how-to-highlight-friends-name-in-facebook-status-update-box-textarea) question of SOF, but that actually does not discuss that.

Anybody there to shed light on it as much as possible?

My choice is jquery.

Answer (score 1):

From a quick glance at facebook, it appears that there is a `<div>` tag that renders the highlighted content along side the text content.

The text is captured one keystroke at a time by onKeyUp events on the `<textarea>` element (transparent and overlayed on top of the div with the visible content) and transposed into the `<div>` element. When examining the key up events, simply check if the key is '@' and fire the menu event.

Comment: how can html be written inside a textarea ?

Comment: HTML is not written inside the textarea. The textarea is transparent - floats above the DIV that contains the HTML.

Comment: The DOM structure is covered in depth in the question you linked to in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure Facebook uses an element with `contenteditable` because the hyperlink appears inline when you type it.

Alternatively, if you don't want to format the name, you could create a new element with the exact same font CSS properties, measure the offset and make the dropdown element appear at the same offset to the `textarea`.

Comment: isn't contenteditable only for html5 (not supported by all browsers)? Really i cannot grasp anything from your reply to start with, Can you please make it easier?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed As far as I know, it's been defined in HTML5 but has been supported by browsers for a long time.

Comment: waiting for clarification from you.